# How to copy text from one tab to another?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am working on an extension that allows me to copy data from a website on one tab to another open on a different tab. The two websites have different origins.
I tried `browser.storage.local` but it doesn't seem to be working:

Storing data:

```
browser.storage.local.set({
  'title': 'some title',
  'date': 'some date'
});
```

Retreiving data:

```
let promise = browser.storage.local.get(['title', 'date']);
promise.then(function(item) {
  console.log ('promise success');
  console.log('title: ', item.title);
}, function(error) {
  console.log('error', error);
});
```

Why is it not working and how do I fix it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, it requires a storage permission. I added the following line to my **Manifest.json** file and it worked:

```
"permissions": ["storage"],
```